# Why is valuelist converting integers to floats?

Tags: coldfusion

ColdFusion's documentation for the `valuelist` function says that it does NOT evaluate the values, and that's how it's always behaved for me in the past. I've used the `valuelist` function many times in the past and have never encountered this issue before. We're using CF9.0.1 but this originally popped up on an instance of CF9.0.

The situation came up as we pull `number` values from an Oracle database, which DOES support float values. The values stored are all integers, not floats. The code below replicates the behavior we're seeing. The data is retrieved via stored procedures which we CAN change (using `CAST`), but would like to avoid if possible.

```
<cfscript>
    qryVLTest = queryNew('member_id') ;
    for ( i = 1; i LTE 10; i=i+1) {
      queryAddRow(qryVLTest,1) ;
      querySetCell(qryVLTest,'member_id',i) ;   
    }
    writedump(qryVLTest) ;
    writeoutput(valuelist(qryVLTest.member_id)) ;
</cfscript>
```

The dump displays the values I expect: integers 1-10.

However, the output of the `valuelist` function is returning the following:

**1,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0**

All values after the first one are being evaluated and converted into floats. Why is this, and how can I prevent this in the future?

Comment: does it still do it if you explicitly set column type: qryVLTest = queryNew('member_id', 'integer'); ?

Comment: In this case, no. But most of the time, I'm pulling `number` values from an Oracle database, usually via stored procedures. That data type can hold floats, but the values stored are all integers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 choices. You could do:

```
querySetCell(qryVLTEst,"member_id","#i#")
```

Which should force a string. Or you can specify INT if that is what you want (as azawaza has indicated).

```
queryNew("member_id","Integer");
```

Comment: Thanks. That works for the example code, but it doesn't work for when we pull data from the database. I updated the question to explain the situation a little more clearly.

Comment: What is the data type in Oracle? Is it something like float with a 0 scale (emulating an int) or is it an actual int datatype?

Comment: If I remember right Oracle has as single "number" type with subtypes for int etc. But that's where my knowledge stops :)  I know you don't want to use cast but perhaps retyping the column as PLS_INTEGER or a subtype of number as INT would fix  it?

Comment: The column itself is a `number`, but the values themselves are emulated integers. Most of us would love to re-type the column, but management would never go for it.

Comment: default NUMBER type in Oracle, iirc, stores the value as number with scale 2, i.e 123456789.00. NUMBER(9) type would store the value as just 123456789. if you can't re-type the column, then you'll have to CAST() it in your storedproc. even if you re-type the column, i do not know if CF (or oracle driver used by cf) would not internally still treat it as float instead of int without CASTing...

Answer (score 3):

I know you said you don't want to use CAST() but perhaps you meant in Oracle. Remember you can CAST in CF as well using Q of a Q.

Run your Oracle Query and then use Query of a Query to recast the number as in

```
<cfquery name="blah" dbtype="query">
SELECT CAST(member_ID AS Integer) AS member_ID
FROM  myFancyPantsOracleQuery
</cfquery>
```

That would do the trick I think.

Comment: Yeah, in Oracle since we try to avoid messing with the stored procedures as much as we can. The QoQ is probably the best solution in our situation. It's just very strange as to why the first value is left as an integer, but the others are evaluated to floats even though CF says it doesn't evaluate the values at all.

Comment: Probably something to do with the Oracle driver would be my guess. sorry there's no perfect solution.